# Removing Conditional Statements

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, conditional-statements

I wonder how to remove the conditional statements and replace it with method. for code without listener, I can do it. but this one has the listener event (arg0), which makes me confused. fyi, this code is in the Main Class, and I want to get rid these code out of the main class.

thanks for your help!!

```
@Override
public void onMotionSensingEvent( MotionSensingEvent arg0) {

    double gradient = 1.38;
    double speed;

    float testpitch = 0;
    testpitch = arg0.getOrientation().getPitch();

    float testroll = 0;
    testroll = arg0.getOrientation().getRoll();

    if (testroll > 16 && flyingControl)
    {
        speed = gradient*testroll-22.1;
        System.out.println("kanan = " + speed);
        ardrone.goRight(speed);
    }
    else if (testroll < (-24) && flyingControl)
    {
        speed = gradient*testroll*-1 - 22.1;
        System.out.println("kiri = " + speed);
        ardrone.goLeft(speed);
    }
    else if (testpitch < (-20) && flyingControl)
    {
        System.out.println("go up");
        ardrone.up();
    }
    else if (testpitch > 20 && flyingControl)
    {
        System.out.println("go down");
        ardrone.down();
    }
    else
    {
        ardrone.stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well you have to make decisions upon the values of testroll and testpitch, so I guess you have to test the conditions anyway. But if you want to do that tests in a separate method, you could go for some signature like `void test( float pitch, float roll )`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231855/how-to-make-this-to-oop

Comment: You could nest it within and "if (flyingControl)" to remove a certain amount of redundancy in your if statements.